# MVC 3.0 Get Value of Dyanmic Check Boxes and radio buttons.mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Greetings,

I've got form that displays dynamic group of checkboxes and Group of radio buttons. What's the best way to retrieve user posted values in MVC 3.0?

I think in Web Form we could use Request.FormCollection, is this possible in mvc 3.0 or there's a better way?

Would be nice to get strongly typed collection of objects if possible.

Thank you heaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve your values in the controller with somewhat the same code:

```
public ActionResult PostThread(FormCollection Values)
{
    threads Thread = new threads();
    Thread.Name = Values["Name"];      

    return View();
}
```

Also if your passing all of the objects data through the form you can try using the following (haven't used it myself yet):

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult PostThread(threads newThread)
{            

    return View();
}
```

This should automatically fill up the values, by matching the names you used in the form to the data id's.

Greetings

Lauw

Comment: Hi Lauw, thanks. I tried using your second option however threads object in my case ViewModel object is always null.

Comment: Hi, yes this wouldn't work for a ViewModel object, this is for binding DataModel classes. I don't see how you are retrieving a ViewModel object in a controller action.. perhaps you could show me your controller action's code